# How to get the path to the java file with the main method (src dir)

Tags: java, dir

I have the following in eclipse

```
EclipseJavaProject
    src/
        some.package
            Program (+main method)
            some.xml
            some.other.resource
```

Note: When running the app, the current dir is set to EclipseJavaProject/ by eclipse

I want to get the path to some.xml and the other resources (relative or absolute).
either:

```
src/some/package/
```

or

```
/path-to-workspace/workspace/EclipseJavaProject/src/some/package/
```

Note: **I want the src/ folder in eclipse, because I output files there. I don't want the bin/ folder.
Is there a quick way?**

So far I have (I don't know how to get the src folder name):

```
public class C {
    public static String C;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.err.println(C);
    }

    static {
        String command = System.getProperty("sun.java.command");
        String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/"+command.substring(0, command.lastIndexOf(".")+1).replaceAll("\\.", File.separator);
        C = dir;
    }
}
```

Comment: Search on tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/retrievingResources.html

Comment: Most of the times I'm in a static method and I don't have 'this'. Also I'm not in a jar file.

Comment: `ClassName.class` is `static` as well.

Comment: This would work well in a jar, but would not give me src/package/some.xml

Comment: I test this on real world applications and **works**. In order for me to reopen the question, edit it and post your exact problem. Retrieving resources from the current package is not a problem because it can be searched on the net and is easy to test.

Comment: I just tried it - it gives me the /bin folder in eclipse. I don't want the bin folder. I want the src/ folder

Comment: You have yo start distinguishing between your project (and its source folders) and the actual application (and how it is distributed).

Comment: Thank you for the condescending comment. I have a reason to want to get the src/ folder.

Comment: Can we reopen this, since I have no answer?